# How to do the reverse of format?

Tags: scheme, racket

the format can turn any type into a string, e.g

```
(define lam-form (list `lambda (list `x ) (list `when (list `> `x 0) (list `* 100 `x ))))
(format "~s" lam-form)
```

result will be: `"(lambda (x) (when (> x 0) (* 100 x)))"`

Then my question is: how to do the reverse? meaning, turn `"(lambda (x) (when (> x 0) (* 100 x)))"` back to `'(lambda (x) (when (> x 0) (* 100 x)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`read`](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/Reading.html?q=read#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29).

```
Welcome to Racket v5.1.3.1.
-> (read (open-input-string "(lambda (x) (when (> x 0) (* 100 x)))"))
'(lambda (x) (when (> x 0) (* 100 x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring only to the use of the "~s" formatting directive, then "read" is the right choice.  See the docs for racket's "printf", then click through on the definition of "write" for more information.

If, on the other hand, you want to reverse *any* use of `format`, then there may be no unique answer; e.g., undoing `(format "~a~a" "abc" "def")` is not possible (in the sense that there are multiple possible calls that produce `abcdef` ).